# How to tell which memory stick is bad?

Tags: memory, imac, memtest

Suspected memory problems after iMac freezes, restarts, etc.
Rember showed Failure/Data Mismatch at local address 0x0000....

iMac (10,1) has configuration with 3 memory sticks: 2Gb, 2Gb and 4Gb.

Is there a way to determine which memory stick is at fault, preferably using software?

Answer (score 3):

The best thing you can do is test one stick of RAM at a time.  That way there can be no possibility of error in determining which stick is bad.  Remove 2 sticks of RAM and test each one individually to see which one is faulty.

There is a memory testing utility for the Mac [here](http://osxdaily.com/2011/05/03/memtest-mac-ram-test/).